# Can't get a script file in Jade | Error 404

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm new to Jade and I'm really strugling with it, I created a simple drag and drop table system, but for some reason I can't use my script file in jade. I have a css and a JS file and I linked both to the jade file, for some reason only the css is connected correctly...

```
script(src='routes/dragdrop.js' type='text/javascript')
```

This is the reference to the "dragdrop.js" file, I put it at the end of the body tag. The console log gives me the following:

```
GET /routes/dragdrop.js 404 20.949 ms - 507
```

What's possibly wrong here?

Comment: There are just two possiblitys: dragdrop.js doesn't exist or the route is wrong

Comment: @Emeeus my index.jade file is located in a folder called "views" and the dragdrop.js file is located in a folder called "routes". The both folders are located in the same directory "sample"...

Answer (score 0):

If you have your file **index.jade** located in `/sample/views/index.jade` and **dragdrop.js** in `/sample/routes/dragdrop.js` then if you want to call dragdrop.js from index.jade you should call it in this way `script(src='../routes/dragdrop.js' type='text/javascript')`.

If you'd need to go back two folders you should use `../..` three `../../..`. and so on.